# Could you provide an example of evil table/font based html code?

Tags: html, css

I have heard about "evil"  and  based HTML, but I have never seen any real-world examples. It seems that nowadays, most websites are using 's and CSS for layout. Van anybody provide an example of this "evil" code? It should be a real-word example.

Comment: One example: http://www.angelfire.com/super/badwebs/

Comment: Ah, you're too late. [Geocities](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GeoCities) ceased to exist about a year ago. It's a walhalla of this kind of sites.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Ironically.** [w3schools.com](http://www.w3schools.com/PHP/func_array.asp)

Comment: Not really ironic, since w3schools's content is extremely unreliable. Actually I'd say their markup isn't *that* unreadable, by the low, low standards of the web at large... :-)

Answer (score 1):

Sure, take a look at the source code of Google. Its tables and font tags galore. Obviously their intentions lie in the area of efficiency as opposed to semantics. I wouldn't call it evil...

Answer (score 0):

If you’ve received any slickly-designed HTML e-mails, they’re likely to be an unmaintainable mess of `<table>` and `<font>` tags under the hood. (Having written and maintained a couple, I speak from bitter experience.)

Answer (score 0):

Lots of nonprofit sites are like this. Here's one I designed a few years ago (but did not develop) and it makes almost exclusive use of tables for the entire site.

http://kenbrookyouth.com/main/main.php